# Unable to match specific string with regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to match html texts converted into strings. But None of my *regex* is working.

Html texts I am trying to match from:

```
"[<span class="instancename">CLASS 8B PHY  | TUE | 9AM to 9:40AM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8AB 2ND LG (HINDI)  | TUE | 10AM to 10:40AM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8AB 2ND LG (BENGALI)  | TUE | 10AM to 10:40AM <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8AB 2ND LG (NEPALI)  | TUE | 10AM to 10:40AM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8B GEOG | TUE | 11AM to 11:40AM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8B BIO | TUE | 12NOON to 12:40PM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8AB CP APP | TUE | 5PM to 5:40PM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8AB CM APP | TUE | 5PM to 5:40PM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>]"
```

The sentences that I want to match are:

1. `CLASS 8B PHY  | TUE | 9AM to 9:40AM`
2. `CLASS 8AB 2ND LG (HINDI)  | TUE | 10AM to 10:40AM`
3. `CLASS 8B GEOG | TUE | 11AM to 11:40AM`

and many more in the html texts above provided

The code that I am using to match these doesn't seems to work:

```
import re
html_text = [<span class="instancename">CLASS 8B PHY  | TUE | 9AM to 9:40AM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8AB 2ND LG (HINDI)  | TUE | 10AM to 10:40AM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8AB 2ND LG (BENGALI)  | TUE | 10AM to 10:40AM <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8AB 2ND LG (NEPALI)  | TUE | 10AM to 10:40AM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8B GEOG | TUE | 11AM to 11:40AM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8B BIO | TUE | 12NOON to 12:40PM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8AB CP APP | TUE | 5PM to 5:40PM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>, <span class="instancename">CLASS 8AB CM APP | TUE | 5PM to 5:40PM<span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span></span>, <span class="accesshide"> BigBlueButtonBN</span>]

regex = re.compile(r'^[CLASS]*[M]')
match = regex.findall(str(html_text))
print(match)
```

I think I am not providing the right *regex* to match

Comment: You're making a common newbie mistake. `[]` is not for grouping, it's for character sets.

Comment: I never understand where new regex users get that misunderstanding. There can't possibly be a tutorial that shows that, is there?

Comment: Do you see `()` in examples and misread it as `[]`?

Comment: Why don't you have quotes around the `html_text` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with HTML, so it makes sense to use BeautifulSoup to parse HTML in Python.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """Your HTML goes here""" # 's' is a string variable I initialized the `doc`ument
doc = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
for span in doc.find_all("span", attrs={'class':"instancename"}):
    innerspans = [x.extract() for x in span.find_all("span", attrs={'class':'accesshide'})]
    print(span.text)
```

Output:

```
CLASS 8B PHY  | TUE | 9AM to 9:40AM
CLASS 8AB 2ND LG (HINDI)  | TUE | 10AM to 10:40AM
CLASS 8AB 2ND LG (BENGALI)  | TUE | 10AM to 10:40AM 
CLASS 8AB 2ND LG (NEPALI)  | TUE | 10AM to 10:40AM
CLASS 8B GEOG | TUE | 11AM to 11:40AM
CLASS 8B BIO | TUE | 12NOON to 12:40PM
CLASS 8AB CP APP | TUE | 5PM to 5:40PM
CLASS 8AB CM APP | TUE | 5PM to 5:40PM
```

Note that `[x.extract() for x in span.find_all("span", attrs={'class':'accesshide'})]` extracts the `span` elements with `accesshide` *class*, and removes them from `span`. So, the actual text left is the `span` text without the text of the inner `span`s.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
regex = re.compile(r'CLASS.*?[\d:]+[AP]M to [\d:]+[AP]M')
```

1. You shouldn't start the pattern with `^`, because then it will only match at the beginning and won't find all the matches.
2. `CLASS` shouldn't be in square brackets. `[CLASS]` matches a single character that's either `C`, `L`, 'A`, or 'S`.
3. You need `.*` to match any text after `CLASS`. And make it non-greedy using `?`.
4. You can't just match `M` at the end, because then it will match the next `M` anywhere in the string. You should only match it after a time and `A` or `P`. And you also need to match the start time and `to`, so it doesn't stop matching at the start time.

Comment: `r'CLASS.*?[\d:]+\w+ to [\d:]+\w+'` for case "CLASS 8B BIO | TUE | 12NOON to 12:40PM"

Comment: They didn't show NOON in the sample output, I didn't notice it in the input.